# How to convert user input hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model I have an attribute "duration" (seconds as an integer) But the views new/edit have input for: hours, minutes, seconds.

Should I have in model (attr_accessor :hours, :minutes, :seconds) then how do I convert these virtual attributes into my "duration" attribute, Coming from Java I'd have setter/getter on "duration"!

Answer (score 6):

You can set a before_save filter to calculate it's value from the values of your virtual accesors (being hours, minutes and seconds). Something like:

```
class Model << AR:Base

  attr_accessor :hours, :minutes, :seconds
  before_save :update_duration

  def update_duration
     duration = = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + secods
  end

end
```

It's a bit rough, but should give you an idea on how it could work. Whenever you call the "save" method on the model (either on a create or update actions), the filter will be called before accesing the BD, update it's value and then proceed to save it properly.

Comment: Params inside a model, are you sure about that ... ?

Comment: Params in the model doesn't make sense!

Comment: You are right, sorry, those were meant for a controller only, not the model. I've adjusted it accordingly.